# Unable to input while trying to call a Python Script using PowerShell on a Remote Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I have a Python Script as shown below stored in a remote computer.

```
print("hello")
a=input("d")
print(a)
```

Im trying to execute this script from my local machine through PowerShell using Invoke-Command as shown below.

```
Invoke-Command -computername COMP1 -credential COMP1\user -scriptblock {python C:\Temp\a.py}
```

But getting the below error, which has to do with input line which is used in the Python Script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : COMP1

  File "C:\Temp\a.py", line 2, in <module>
    a=input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed with this?

Comment: This look more like an issue with the file/indentation that the code or its syntax.

Comment: The same python script works when I run locally. Doubt if its related to indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) does *not* support running *interactive* console applications** (those that read from stdin) (as of PowerShell 7.2.x).

Therefore, your attempt to read from stdin via `input()` fails.

Note that the problem doesn't just affect [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) calls, but also explicitly interactive sessions entered with [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession).

---

**While you can *not* work around this limitation per se, you can at least  provide *automated responses*** to stdin-based prompts, by providing them *as pipeline input* (`-Credential` argument omitted for brevity):

```
'some response' | 
  Invoke-Command -computername COMP1 { python C:\Temp\a.py }
```

<sup>Note: P.S., For better or worse, PowerShell invariably *appends a trailing newline* to strings sent through the pipeline to external programs - see [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974). Therefore, sending `'some response'` implicitly includes the newline that acts as the <kbd>Enter</kbd> that submits the response.</sup>

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, you can similarly provide this response as part of the remotely executing code:

```
Invoke-Command -computername COMP1 { 'some response' | python C:\Temp\a.py }
```

If you need a truly interactive remote solution, consider use of a utility such as [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), but note that it uses a different remoting transport.

Comment: @KarthikKolle, there is no workaround per se, unfortunately, but you can provide _automated_ responses to interactive prompts, if that helps - please see my update. If you need true interactive support, you'll have to use a utility such as `psexec`.

Comment: P.S., @Mathias: For better or worse, PowerShell invariably appends a trailing newline to strings sent through the pipeline to external programs, so appending ``"`rn"`` would send an extra newline - see [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to PowerShell's remoting not supporting running interactive console applications as rightly pointed out by @mklement0 and @Mathias is as follows

Sample Python Script which accepts two command line arguments

```
import sys
print("Hello")
n = len(sys.argv)
for i in range(1, n):
    print(sys.argv[i])
```

Before running Invoke-command, create two new variables $greet1 and $greet2 in PowerShell with required strings as shown below and then pass the same two variables within the script blocking using the $using feature available in PS 3.X+

```
$Greet1 = "Hello There"
$Greet2 = "Welcome"
Invoke-Command -computername COMP1 -credential COMP1\Administrator -scriptblock {python C:\Temp\sc.py $using:Greet1 $using:Greet2}
```

It works as expected!

[image]

*This solution is only for a sample code, but should be able to implement it similarly for a complex script where we need to input multiple variables.*